# Is there any decentralized and secure alternative to QuickNode?

Tags: wallet, api, flutter

I want to develop a Solana wallet using the Flutter framework. So far it is possible using the QuckNode API service. However, I think it is not a safe approach to rely on a centralized service. What is the right alternative?

Source Code: https://github.com/AminMemariani/send-nft-sol-qn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each individual RPC Node is centralized by design. The RPC Node consists of an API backed up by a single validator instance. However, given that Solana has 3000+ nodes in total (counting both RPC and validator nodes), the consumer of the RPC has the luxury of not depending on any single one of these validators.

Instead, you could grab a bunch of RPCs. Maybe one from alchemy, QuickNode and Helius each to start with, although there are many more.

You can then deploy something like a round-robin proxy (like haproxy) on top of the endpoints. That may work for your use case, if the primary motivation is to reduce dependency on a single RPC provider.